# How do I initialize a variable in Apollo Client 3

Tags: react-apollo, apollo-client

Hey I'm trying to learn Apollo Client v3 but I can't wrap my head around the docs and the new local state management.

I want to have a state which remembers the month and the year last used.
This is what I have in my old Apollo when I create a new ApolloClient

```
clientState: {
  defaults: {
    currentMonth: 8,
    currentYear: 2020,
  },
},
```

So trying to understand the new docs this is what I tried

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache({
    typePolicies: {
        clientState: {
            fields: {
                month: 8,
                year: 2020,
            },
        },
    },
});
```

But with no luck. I feel really dumb for not understanding the docs but it's hard to find anything that resembles my question.
Right now I'm really close to swap to Redux but still hoping for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reactive variables in the Apollo Client 3.

[https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/local-state/reactive-variables/#:~:text=New%20in%20Apollo%20Client%203,application%20without%20using%20GraphQL%20syntax](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/local-state/reactive-variables/#:%7E:text=New%20in%20Apollo%20Client%203,application%20without%20using%20GraphQL%20syntax).

For your example:

**Define**

```
import { makeVar } from '@apollo/client';

export const currentMonth = makeVar(8);
export const currentYear = makeVar(2020);
```

**Get**

```
import { currentMonth, currentYear } from "./yourPath/yourFile";

// Output: 8
console.log(currentMonth());

// Output: 2020
console.log(currentYear());
```

**Set**

```
import { currentMonth, currentYear } from "./yourPath/yourFile";

currentMonth(9);
    
// Output: 9
console.log(currentMonth());
    
currentYear(2021);
    
// Output: 2021
console.log(currentYear());
```

Comment: Something relevant that I am trying to figure out.

I want to use reactive variables as state management and want to initialize the variables from some data which I will fetch from a graphql server.

Are there any recommended way to do it?